# actualizar un iframe con un archivo de texto dentro

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Buenos dias mi consuta es referente a un iframe, bueno pues he hecho una web donde tengo un boton para crear cuentas automaticas, esto funciona de la siguiente manera.
El boton crear cuenta tiene un script en php que lo que hace es coger la primera linea de un .txt, copiarlo al .txt del usuario y borrar esa primera linea del .txt donde estan todas las cuentas.
Luego en la pagina del usuario tiene un iframe donde se muestra ese .txt que ya a copiado.
Bueno la cuestion viene aqui: 
Si yo le doy al boton de crear cuenta a veces no sale en el iframe la cuenta copiada, si no que tengo que recargar la pagina. Entonces le he puesto un script en java para que autorefresque el iframe cada 5 segundos, pero se me presenta el problema de que cuando hay varias cuentas en el mismo .txt del usuario no se puede llegar a la ultima por el tiempo....

Resumiendo:
Lo que el script php es coger la primera linea del archivo comun donde estan todas las cuentas que he creado yo (todalascuentas.txt) y copiarlo al usuario.txt cuando el usuario le da al boton (Crear cuentas) y tambien a su vez borra la primera linea cogida que a copiado en usuario.txt
Y el usuario.txt es lo que se muestra en el iframe. Lo que pasa es que dependiendo de la demora del script te lo muestra o no y hay que refrescar la web completa, por eso puse el script en java para que actualice solo el iframe cada 5 segundos (en bucle). Y lo que necesito es que lo actualice a los 5 segundos y que pare (que no haya bucle)  de que el usuario le de al boton crear cuenta

Codigo:

```
Javascript
<script type='text/javascript'>
var iframe = document.getElementById('snakenet');
var refreshInterval = 1000 * 5; // Refresh every 5 seconds
setInterval(function() {
  iframe.src = iframe.src;
}, refreshInterval); 
</script>


boton:
<a href="./index.php?bin=verdu"><img src="./img/crearusuario.png" onmouseover="this.src='./img/crearusuario2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='./img/crearusuario.png';"/width="100%" height=100%></a>



Iframe

<iframe id="snakenet" width="100%"  height="100%"  frameborder="1" border="1" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" src="/usuario/usuario.txt"/align="middle"></iframe>
```

Comment: ¿Un script en Java?  ¿Has pensado en solucionar esto mejor mediante Ajax, sin utilizar `iframe`?

Comment: Pues si te digo la verdad @A.Cedano estoy empezando en esto de la programacion web y no tengo ni idea de como solucionarlo con ajax.. podrias ilustrarme?

Comment: Si estás iniciando de esta manera (con `iframe`)  eres un valiente. Leyendo tu pregunta creo que es mucho más simple hacerlo con Ajax, desde una sola página, sin tener que refrescarla. Lo que pasa es que la pregunta no es clara: en un momento hablas de Java ¿?  y luego, no se entiende bien lo del archivo en el cliente... ¿es un archivo de texto que está del lado del cliente? Sería bueno que aclares tu pregunta y podemos intentar una solución.

Comment: @A.Cedano haber si me puedo explicar bien jeje, haber es una web privada donde el usuario se loguea y cada usuario tiene su index.php.... su carpeta independiente etc... dentro de su carpeta hay un archivo llamado usuarios.txt que es lo que muestra el iframe.

Lo que el script php es coger la primera linea del archivo comun donde estan todas las cuentas que he creado yo (todalascuentas.txt) y copiarlo al usuario.txt cuando el usuario le da al boton (Crear cuentas) y tambien a su vez borra la primera linea cogida que a copiado en usuario.txt

Comment: Cualquier aclaración ponla en la pregunta directamente, no en un comentario. Si los archivos están en el servidor mejor todavía, eso es pan comido con Ajax, pero aclara las cosas editando la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: he editado el mensaje  anterior y la pregunta @A.Cedano si todos los archivos estan en el servidor

Comment: Me parece que esto es bastante sencillo de hacer, sin `iframe` ni historias complicadas. Si quieres olvida el `iframe`, de entrada queda descartado para esto porque no lo necesitas, y céntrate en explicar mejor el problema. Hay un archivo que tiene todas las cuentas, pero varios usuarios pueden acceder a ese archivo de forma concurrente... por ejemplo, ¿por qué tienes esa información en un archivo? ¿por qué se borra la primera línea cuando un usuario abre ese archivo con todas las cuentas? ¿por qué esa info no se guarda en una base de datos?, etc. Explica eso en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano 1 los usuarios solo pueden ver en el iframe las cuentas que a copiado el script php de todaslascuentas.txt. 2 la primera linea se borra para si hay dos usuarios pidiendo cuentas no le de la misma. 3 La verdad es que no tengo ni idea de base de datos jeje y vi esta forma facil.

Comment: Esto se puede hacer con un archivo pero es muy precario y vas a tener que controlar de alguna forma cuando hay alguien sobre el archivo, sea activando un indicador en esa fila o bloqueando el archivo (lo cual impediría que varios lo abran a la vez, siendo un problema serio). En estos casos lo mejor es una base de datos. Se puede intentar lo que propones en la pregunta, pero creo que no resuelve de fondo tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar ajax para cuando el php termine de procesar el iframe, se actualize sin necesidad de hacer un setTimeout

```js
var iframe = $("#snakenet");

function crearUsuario(event){
  event.preventDefault() // DESACTIVO EL HREF POR DEFECTO
  var el = $(event.target); // SELECCIONO EL NODO </a>
  var bin = el.attr("data-bin"); // COJO DEL ATRIBUTO DATA-BIN EL VALOR
  
  $.ajax({
    url: './index.php?bin='+bin,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
      // CUANDO TERMINE DE PROCESAR EJECUTAMOS EL RELOAD DEL IFRAME
      iframe.get(0).contentDocument.location.reload() // 
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id="snakenet" width="100%"  height="100%"  frameborder="1" border="1" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" src="/usuario/usuario.txt"/align="middle"></iframe>

<a onclick="crearUsuario(event)" href="#" data-bin="verdu"><img src="./img/crearusuario.png" onmouseover="this.src='./img/crearusuario2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='./img/crearusuario.png';"/width="100%" height=100%></a>
```

Comment: el primer cuadro de codigos va en Head no? estoy muy verde aun jejeje

Comment: La primera parte ponla al final y la segunda en el head

Comment: @Jorege Bowen te pongo el codigo de mi index.php en la pregunta y me dices que hago mal please

Comment: Añade en tu head la librería jquery que está justo antes del iframe en mi respuesta

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CWVh4gHm  ese es mi index.php @Jorge Bowen

Comment: Al final tienes un script que llama a jquery y bootstrap elimina el de jquery y el de bootstrap lo pones debajo del jquery que tienes en el head

Comment: no funciona no lanza el script ( tiene sus permisos y demas todo)

Comment: Pon un alert(1) después del event. Preventdefault

Comment: event.preventDefault() alert(1) sigue sin lanzar el script